# Why Does Type.GetType fail on the .NET Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: compact-framework

I am trying to de-serialize a XML string back to an object. The code does NOT have a reference to the assembly that has the class definition. We keep the fully qualified name in the XML document using `XmlTextWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction`, so we use that to get the type at runtime.

```
GetType( fullyQualifiedAssemblyName, false, true );
```

This of course works perfectly on the full framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because the ignoreCase #3 parameter cannot be true in the compact framework. Apparently case insensitive searching is not supported in the Compact Framework. Turning on the throwOnError option in parameter 2 helped me identify the problem.

I don't see any documentation that describes this behavior so I thought I would post it here.